# after installing pyqt5designer, designer.exe command not working

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have installed Pyqt5 and pyqt5 designer on gitbash and have tried to run the command designer.exe however nothing happens. What is supposed to happen is that designer pops up on to your screen ready for you to use but for me nothing happens. There isn't even a sign of something running. I have installed everything in my virtual environment and ran everything in my virtual environment. In general pyqt5 works as in the fact that I can run pieces of code that I have written without any problem but I cant open designer with the command designer.exe

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem I needed to install qt from the qt website.